# Jenkins: SVN branch using svnmerge plugin

Tags: maven, svn, jenkins, branch

We tried to examine jenkins svnmerge plugin what it can do for us to minimize efforts for automatic branching from SVN. So we checked the option "Accept Integration from Subversion feature branches" and created a new branch. This runs very easy and fine but there are a few drawbacks, we could not resolve yet:

- jenkins does branching from trunk. Is it also possible to create a branch from a freshly created tag?
- the new branch does not contain the incremented version number in the pom.xml. Can this be done by additional configuration?
- the new branch does not contain the updated scm-connection-tag (/trunk to /branches) in the pom.xml. Can this be done by additional configuration?

Answer (score 1):

- I use my own branching strategy with "Execute Batch/Shell" step and command line SVN.
- I use my own ant script to go through the pom.xml and replace the version number via regex.
- Use **[JobCopy Builder](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jobcopy+Builder+plugin)** when using your own branching strategy, have a "template" job, and copy from it with JobCopy and modify parameters as needed.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This is not exactly what we were looking for, but maybe it's the way to go. I wonder why this might not be possible with the plugin. The maven release plugin is also capable of doing correct version increments on tags...